# Routing call audio to HDMI

Tags: audio, calls, hdmi, mhl

I have samsung S5 running android marshmallow. I have connected it to my TV via hdmi cable.  Whenever I make a  whatsapp video call to S5,    video is shown on TV but call audio comes only from phone speaker, not from TV speaker.

What do I need to do to route call audio to tv speaker ?
I have tried soundabout app from playstore, but it does not seem to be working. I have rooted it. Any command from terminal that could do the trick or any other app ?

Comment: My experience on S9 is this with WhatsApp and Duo. Really annoying.